# Psycopg2 - SQL script returning no output

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to pass a few arguments as variable to a SQL script but I am having issues returning an output.

Given below is my code:

```
start_date = '2020-03-01'
end_date = '2020-03-02'
```

I pass these into the below query

```
cursor.execute('select bill_number from table 
                where created_at between {} and {}'.format(start_date, end_date))
```

The above returns no output but I know data exists for this SQL script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing a query you need to **fetch** the results:

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

It is **very important** that you don't use `format` for SQL queries as it's susceptible to SQL injection attacks; instead use:

```
query = "select bill_number from table where created_at between %s and %s"
cursor.execute(query, (start_date, end_date))
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

If you want to add filters you just need to adjust the query and add the parameter:

```
query = "select bill_number from table where created_at between %s and %s and product=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (start_date, end_date, product))
```

In order to use a list as parameter you can use `IN` and a `tuple`:

```
>>> query = "select * from clients where added between %s and %s and score in %s"
>>> data = ('2019-01-01', '2020-03-01', tuple([1,2,3]))
>>> cursor.execute(query, data)
>>> rows = cursor.fetchall()
>>> len(rows)
32
>>>
```

Make sure you read the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) as they contain a lot of valuable information.

Comment: thanks that helped. just another quick help if I were to add another filter `product = 'prod_a' ` how could I edit the above query

`sql equivalent : "select bill_number from table where created_at between %s and %s and product = 'prod_a"`

I tried passing product = (%s) and passed that argument but that doesn't work

Comment: @ioniut ticus the issue I have is product variable is a list and hence I am having issue

Comment: For a list parameter you can either use `and product IN %s` in the SQL query and `(start_date, end_date, tuple(products))` for the arguments or use a `for` loop.

Comment: I tried passing products as per the suggestion but I get SyntaxError: arguments of row IN must all be row expressions.. I am trying to pass in multiple products (prod_a, prod_b, prod_c).